# Android: Random Word Generator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, random, textview

I have this so far but i cant fine whats wrong, sorry for the dumb question, im new to all this.
I also posted the error it gives me for further reference

```
package com.example.randomword;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String[] quotes = new String[] {"q1", "q2", "q3"};
String randomQuote = quotes[(int) (Math.random() * quotes.length)];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//Make a new text view passing Activity object
TextView quote = new TextView(R.id.quote);
//Set a text into view

quote.setText(quotes);             <--- Error here "The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (String[])"
//set the view into activity view container
setContentView(quote);

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not set the Array of Strings in the `TextView` besides set the String only as below You can not set the `String array` in `TextView`:

```
quote.setText(randomQuote);
```

Answer (score 1):

Quotes is an array of strings, not just one string. You want to use

```
quote.setText(randomQuote);
```

If you do want to set the value to the string array, for example spread by new lines you could do:

```
String quotesString = "";
for(String s : quotes) 
    quoteString += s + "\n";
quote.setText(quotesString);
```

Comment: Now im getting an error on 
    TextView quote = new TextView(R.id.quote); "TextView(int) is undefined"

Comment: No problem. For the new error, try TextView quote = new TextView(this);

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a array of Strings to `setText` method of `TextView`. That is the problem.
`quotes` is declared as :

> String[] quotes = new String[] {"q1", "q2", "q3"};

Then you wrote:

> quote.setText(quotes);

You need to pass only one `String` to `setText`
either:

> quote.setText(randomQuote);

or

> quote.setText(quotes[i]); // where i is an integer denoting index of the element in `quotes`